# Use REST API to get the current site collection

Tags: javascript, rest

I have a list for links in my footer that I'm using REST to populate.

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('FooterLinks')/items",
    type: "GET",
    headers: {
        "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
    },
    success: function (data) {
        $.each(data.d.results, function (index, item) {
            $('#FooterLinks-placeholder').append("<dl id='" + item.columnID + "'><dt>" + item.Title + "</dt></dl>");
        });
    },
    error: function (error) {
        //alert(JSON.stringify(error));
    }
});
```

I just created a new site collection under the root `/eu/` that has a copy of the list so the links can be independent of the root. I'm trying to use the same javascript (because there will be more regional site collections) across all of them but am unsure how to get the current site collection in as a variable into my request to make it something like:

```
url: "/{sitecollection}/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('FooterLinks')/items",
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `_spPageContextInfo.siteAbsoluteUrl` for getting the site collection url. For more info, refer : http://blah.winsmarts.com/2013-2-_sppagecontextinfo_is_your_new_best_friend.aspx